# How to extract date and temporal expressions from German text in Python?

Tags: python, date, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to extract dates and other temporal expressions from unstructured written texts in German language, including formats such as

- 'Es ist der 1. Januar 2020.'
- 'Gestern hat es geschneit.'
- 'Heute Abend ab 18 Uhr eine Stunde'
- '2023-02-28'
- '4 Tage ab Montag'
- 'Bis 20.03.2023'
- 'Von Donnerstag den 18. bis zum 21. Mai'
- 'Samstag 18.03.'
- '2023-03-15.'
  Other temporal expressions that I want to extract include
- 'nächste Woche'
- 'im letzten Monat'
- 'in 2 Stunden'
- and more.

I followed [this guide](https://www.qualicen.de/natural-language-processing-timeline-extraction-with-regexes-and-spacy/) for named entity recognition and applied the test case on the following python packages:

- spaCy models (de_core_news_md, de_core_news_lg, de_dep_news_trf, en_core_web_lg)
- [spaCy_stanza](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza) (`nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline("de", package="hdt")`)
- datefinder
- htmldate, after reading this [persuading article](https://adrien.barbaresi.eu/blog/evaluation-date-extraction-python.html)
- dateutil parser (and other parsers)

For comparison I translated [the English text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qualicen/timeline/master/history_of_germany.txt) in the mentioned guide to German, using google translate. Then I executed the different tools on the text, as well on the given text snippets.

The English spaCy model en_core_web_lg is able to find 596 dates and temporal expressions, including both specific dates like 'January 1st, 2020' and more general expressions like 'the next decade' and 'a Christmas holiday'. It can also recognize time periods, such as 'the summer of 1989' and 'the early 1950s', as well as relative expressions like 'four weeks later', 'six months', and 'two days later'.

However, I was not able to get the German spaCy models to recognize a single date or temporal expression in the translated text or the text snippets given above. I saved the translation in a local file, and it is easily readable, containing string snippets like "im Jahr 1907" and "Zwischen 1994 und 1998." Just to check, I printed an excerpt to the terminal and checked the type, being <class 'str'>. Interestingly, the English spaCy model was able to recognize 333 dates in the German text! The other packages, spacy_stanza, datefinder, and htmldate, were also not able to recognize any dates on the German text.

This is the basic setup I am using:

```
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in filter(lambda e: e.label_=='DATE',doc.ents):
    print(ent.text)
```

The labels assigned to the requested dates above:

```
1. ADJA adjective, attributive
Januar NN noun, singular or mass
2020. NE proper noun
Gestern ADV adverb
21. ADJA adjective, attributive
Mai NN noun, singular or mass
heute ADV adverb
```

After consulting the [spaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/models/de), I noticed that the German word list de_core_news_lg does not include any NER-label for dates or other temporal expressions. To confirm this, I retrieved the list of available labels using the following code:

```
for label in label_list:
  print(label, spacy.explain(label))
```

(Unfortunately, the `PDAT` label turned out to be an `attributive demonstrative pronoun`.) In comparison to the English word list, the only available NER-related labels in the German word list are `LOC`, `MISC`, `ORG`, and `PER`. Therefore, none of the four German spaCy word lists are suitable for recognizing dates or temporal expressions.

In similar threads on stackoverflow it was suggested using regex. Regex can be an effective approach, although it is limited to the covered date formats. Nevertheless I read that NLTK offers a regex-approach, which I could include in the final solution (together with some NER model training). For now I'm looking for a solution in Python, that reaches comparable efficiency to the English model on english text.

To sum up, the applied NER methods cannot recognize dates since they lack a specific NER label for them. However, I found that the en_core_web_lg model for English date recognition is able to detect dates in an English text and about half as many in a German text.

Currently, the best solution I can think of is to translate the text to English and use the English model for date recognition. However, this would be a workaround.

Comment: *"Is there any word list for the German language comprising NER-date labeling"* - This question seems to be off-topic on Stack Overflow, as you're requesting off-site resources instead of help with a problem.

Comment: @MichaelM. Thank you for your reply. I edited the question, so it states my initial programming related problem and is open for any suggested solution. I hope like this it fits better in.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [de_core_news_lg](https://spacy.io/models/de) SpaCy docs, the German model does not include the 'DATE' label for the supported NER labels, whereas the English [en_core_web_lg](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_lg) does contain it.

A solution could be to create a Custom Named Entity Recognition (NER). Using a Custom NER, you're able to create your own labels. Thus, you will be able to create the 'DATE' label yourself. You can find plenty of tutorials online on how to set up such a model, and the documentation can be found on [this link](https://spacy.io/usage/training). The downside of this approach is that you will need to train the custom NER yourself, which will be time-consuming and requires a training dataset. Note that this is an entirely new model, and it will not detect the labels that are present in the de_core_news_lg.

If you also need the labels in the de_core_news_lg model, you can try to combine the two trained models explained in [this tutorial](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials).

Prodigy is a good tool to obtain training datasets, a product developed by the developers of SpaCy. However, it is not free. If you do not want to spend money, you can do everything yourself.